# Why should I use unsigned char?

Tags: c

I saw unsigned char used in the return part in two different codes. What is the reason for using unsigned char in this way?

```
int ft_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    if (!n)
        return (0);
    while ((s1[i] == s2[i]) && s1[i] && s2[i] && i < n)
        i++;
    return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
}
```

and this

```
int ft_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    if (!n)
        return (0);
    while ((s1[i] == s2[i]) && s1[i] && s2[i] && i < n)
        i++;
    return (*(unsigned char *)s1[i] - *(unsigned char *)s2[i]);
}
```

I believe it's related to Unicode characters, but I have a question in mind. For example, when using a character that is not in the standard ASCII table (e.g., 'i', 'ö'), wouldn't it remain unchanged when I interpret it with the char data type? In that case, what does using unsigned char in the return part mean?

Comment: Hello, you should add more context. For example, the source: https://github.com/MrRobb/42_piscine/blob/master/day05/ex07/ft_strncmp.c.

Comment: Where did you see the second example?  `return (*(unsigned char *)s1[i] - *(unsigned char *)s2[i]);` looks like spectacularly bad code.  `[]` array subscripting has higher precedence than the cast to `unsigned char *` does, so that code takes `char` values, casts that `char` **value** to a pointer, then dereferences it.

Comment: @Hüseyin Ateş  This statement return (*(unsigned char *)s1[i] - *(unsigned char *)s2[i]); is just incorrect and invokes undefined behavior because values of the type char are interpreted as pointers.:)

Comment: Your first example returns a signed `int` not `unsigned char` and does not cast anything to `unsigned char` ?

Comment: This code is wrong. Posit: `...ncmp( "a", "ab", 1 );` This code **will** return the value of `0 - 'b'`... Bad code for a beginner to be reading,,,

Comment: See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/xMovj8bfx It all depends on the implicit conversion and promotion rules.

Answer (score 1):

If char is 8bit then if the MS bit is set it becomes a negative number. If you want to compare characters codes >= 128 then you would get unexpected effects.

Example. The code is 128(unsigned) then as signed char it would be  -128.

If you substract 127 from 128 you would expect 1 but as unsigned char you will get `-128`

That it is why author is using unsigned chars. But he is not doing what he thinks is doing. His code invokes undefined behaviour.

It should be:

```
return (unsigned char)s1[i] - (unsigned char )s2[i];
```

Comment: Will modern compilers complain about removing the const in that subtraction even though there are no writes to the values?  (Just curious, I work with C++ not C)

Comment: @DaveS: There is no `const` in the operand of the `(unsigned char)` cast. The nominal operand is `s1[i]`, for the first cast. This is an lvalue for an element in the array. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, when an lvalue is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or `++` or `--`, the operand of unary `&`, or the left operand of `.` or an assignment operator, it is automatically converted to the value stored in the designated object, and “If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue…”. So it is an `unsigned char` value, no `const`.

Comment: Example. The code is 128(unsigned) then as signed char it would be -128.

If you substract 127 from 128 you would expect 1 but as unsigned char you will get -128                                                                                                                                                           Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

The `ft_strncmp` routine appears to be intended to emulate the standard `strncmp` routine, notwithstanding its several errors. The C standard says this about its string handling routines, in C 2018 7.24.1 3:

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

Therefore, to conform to the C standard, even though the routine is declared to have parameters of type `const char *`, it must interpret the data they point to as elements of `unsigned char`.

The string parameters of `strncmp` are declared `const char *` even though the data is interpreted as `unsigned char` for historic reasons, involving how the C language developed and that it was grown experimentally by different people at different times, rather than planned.

If you are not writing a routine to emulate the C standard library routines or to interact with them, you do not always need to use `unsigned char`. It is entirely reasonable to have your own string handling routines that treat characters as `char` or `signed char` if that suits your needs.

> For example, when using a character that is not in the standard ASCII table (e.g., 'i', 'ö'), wouldn't it remain unchanged when I interpret it with the char data type?

The C standard requires that characters in the *basic character set* have nonnegative values (when stored in a `char`, C 2018 6.2.5 3). The basic execution character set includes the Latin alphabet in uppercase and lowercase, the decimal digits, 29 graphic characters:

```
! " # % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ;  ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
```

space, and control characters for horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, alert, backspace, carriage return, and new line.

Other characters are allowed to have negative values, in which case interpreting their bits as an `unsigned char` produces different values for them. So, when writing code dealing with characters, you may need to be sensitive to potential differences between `char` and `unsigned char`.